# Codeigniter query and structure

Tags: codeigniter

I have a model with two queries:

```
function listCategories()
{
     $result=$this->db->query("select * from table")->result();
     return $result;
}

function listSubCategories($var)
{
     $result=$this->db->query("select * from table where field=$var")->result();
     return $result;
}
```

Then i call the first function on my controller:

```
$data['rows']=$this->my_model->listCategories();
```

The problem is: now i need to call the second function (listSubCategories()) and the $var that i need to pass to it, is a field from the database which is returned by the listCategories() function

What's the best way to handle a situation like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the return from the first function into your call for the second function:

```
$data=$this->my_model->listCategories();

$sub=$this->my_model->listSubCategories($data->row()->field_name);
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for your input. I tried your suggestion but i got an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in (...)`

Comment: Try removing ->result() from your listCategories function

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks again for your help. I think your solution may not be what im looking for. The row() method only returns one row. What im looking for is something like (in view): `foreach ($categories as $category) { echo '<h1>'.$category->title.'</h1>'; foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) { echo '<h2>'.$subcategory->title.'</h2>'; } }`